# NetSuite Webstore Login using In-Bound SSO for OPENID connect

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, netsuite, suitecommerce

We have a websotre at NetSuite hosted at custom domain , we are trying to implement SSO login using OPENID connect, but when user logins at the identiy server or if already logged in there, it never returns back to the Netsuite WebStore Domain, we are looking for some solutions and help on that, we have tried every steps and documentation provided inside ORACLE NetSuite side.

SSO Login to Suite commerce store USING OPENID Connect Approach.